# Fold/reduce boolean values in masked loss function Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm building a Seq-to-Seq translation model in which there is a custom loss function.
The loss function must find the `end_token` of the output sequences and apply `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss only over the elements which are in sequence.

So to picture the problem here is an example of the desired result:

```
mask = [[False, False, True, False],
        [False, True, False, False],
        [True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, True]]

output_mask = [[True, True,  True,  False],
               [True, True,  False, False],
               [True, False, False, False],
               [True, True,  True,  True]]
```

One way I could think of would be to map rows and apply foldr with accumulative `or` operation, but the code below does not work...

```
  example_lambda = Lambda(lambda val: K.any(K.stack(val)))
  row_lambda = Lambda(lambda row: K.foldr(example_lambda, row, initializer=K.variable(False)))
  output_mask = K.map_fn(row_lambda, mask)
```

What would be the fastest matrix manipulation principle to achieve the desired results?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try the `cumsum` approach, but I don't know whether it will be faster.

Assuming one token per sentence:

```
endToken = number

def loss1(true, pred):

    #assuming pred is (batch, length, categorical_size)
    predLabels = K.argmax(pred, axis=-1) #(batch, length)
    endTokens = K.cast(K.equal(predLabels, endToken), K.floatx()) #(batch, length)
    outputMask = 1 - K.cumsum(endTokens, axis=-1) #(batch, length)


    #do the rest
```

Assuming all the trailings are full of tokens:

```
endToken = number

def loss1(true, pred):

    #assuming pred is (batch, length, categorical_size)
    predLabels = K.argmax(pred, axis=-1) #(batch, length)
    outputMask = K.cast(K.not_equal(predLabels, endToken), K.floatx()) #(batch, length)


    #do the rest
```

Assuming more than one token can appear, but not guaranteed that the entire trailings are tokens:

```
endToken = number

def loss1(true, pred):

    #assuming pred is (batch, length, categorical_size)
    predLabels = K.argmax(pred, axis=-1) #(batch, length)
    endTokens = K.cast(K.equal(predLabels, endToken), K.floatx()) #(batch, length)
    outputMask = 1 - K.cumsum(endTokens, axis=-1) #(batch, length)
    outputMask = K.clip(outputMask, 0,1)

    #do the rest
```